# How to fix this TypeError for movement animation in Pygame?

Tags: python, class, oop, typeerror, instance

This is my first time coding a game so the answer to this is probably simple but I've been struggling with it for ages. I am attempting to make the movement for the game but I keep receiving this error:

**TypeError: Animation.update_animation() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given**

This is what I've tried

Here is the segment of the code for the Animation class:

```py
def update_animation(self, x_movement, y_movement, right, left, up, down):
        # Updates the animation frame if the cooldown time has passed
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if current_time - self.last_update >= self.animation_cooldown:
            self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % self.animation_frames
            self.last_update = current_time


        # What frames are outputted depending on player movement
        if x_movement: #animations for moving along the x-axis
            if left:
                self.current_animation_frames = self.move_left
            elif right:
                self.current_animation_frames = self.move_right
        elif y_movement: #moving along the y axis
            if up:
                self.current_animation_frames = self.move_up
            elif down:
                self.current_animation_frames = self.move_down
        else:
             self.current_animation_frames = self.idle
```

And here is the code inside the `Character` class where I'm calling the method `update_animation`:

```py
# changes animation frame
self.player_animation.update_animation(x_movement, y_movement, left, right, up, down)
# draws the player sprite with the current animation frame
screen.blit(self.player_animation.get_current_frame(), (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
```

I am very stuck because I do not know what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Clarification for comment

```
#creating the player instance
player = Character(x=400, y=400)

#game loop
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    #background color
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    #drawing player
    player.draw(screen)

    #update display
    pygame.display.update()

    #frame rate
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This is not a problem related to Pygame or animations. This is just a basic problem with python and object oriented programming

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the code where you initialize the object that the class method is being called on and the line where the class method is called? Hard to say further what's wrong without seeing that.

If the exception is telling you that too many positional arguments were given it may have expected the variables passed to be inside a wrapper or iterable type of some kind. Typically this can be resolved by calling the class method with a * in front of tuple/list/iterable that contains all the method's positional arguments.

Ie.

```
player = Player(0, 0, spriteImg, **kwargs)
player.player_animation.update_animation(*(False, True, False, False, True, False))
screen.blit(player.player_animation.get_current_frame(), (player.rect.x, player.rect.y))
```

You should also note that calling the animation_update() method inside the class isn't going to make any changes unless you're dynamically passing kb/mouse inputs to the class instance. You can however use the inherited update hook from pygame.sprite.Sprite (if inheriting from Sprite) to take the necessary animation arguments and pass them down to a call of player_animation.update_animation() and then run screen.blit with the resulting object. Ex.

```
def update(**kwargs):
    aniupdate = self.player_animation.update_animation(**kwargs)
    screen.blit(aniupdate, (self.coords))
```

Comment: I was struggling to show you the code where I initialized the object inside this comment so I added it into my initial post, hope this is okay. 

Thank you for this response, so you are saying there are multiple issues in my code that are causing this error ?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not seeing where you call player.update_animation. I see you call player.draw() and I assume that self draw() calls self.update_animation() but I can't see what values are passed and where without seein how update_animation gets called.